# 301 Redirect Root URL https to http in htaccess using modrewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been unable to find an answer to how to redirect only the https version of the root domain to the http version, and leave the subpages and subfolders untouched.

For example, I would like

```
[this is not a link]https://www.domain.com to point to http://www.domain.com
[this is not a link]https://www.domain.com/ to point to http://www.domain.com
```

I have several other rewrite rules in place, but unable to figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Does RewriteCond have to be declared before each time RewriteRule occurs?

Comment: Not always but in case yes since it is making sure we are redirecting from `https => http`